# Interacting with an ActiveX document using Javascript

Tags: c++, dll, activex, activexobject

I have a HTML page with an embedded ActiveX object. This object is referenced as an OBJECT tag.

The activeX handles some data inside a listview-like control. I need to get the data inside that listview control.
I use the following code:

```
  int msg;
  DWORD lRes = NULL ;
  IHTMLDocument2 *pDoc= NULL;
  IHTMLElementCollection *pElement = NULL;
  IDispatch *ppvDisp;
  VARIANT ObjName;
  _variant_t index = NULL;
  HRESULT hr;
  LRESULT lr;
  UINT *cntTypeInf ;

  OleInitialize(NULL);

  msg = RegisterWindowMessage(L"WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
  lr = SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, msg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, &lRes);
  hr = ObjectFromLresult((LRESULT)lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument2, 0, (void**)&pDoc);
  hr = pDoc->get_all( &pElement );

  BSTR BStrObjName = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR((const char *)"S_DetectCom");
  ObjName.vt = VT_BSTR ;
  ObjName.bstrVal = BStrObjName ;
  hr = pElement->item( ObjName , index , &ppvDisp );
  hr = ppvDisp->GetTypeInfoCount(cntTypeInf);
```

The ppvDisp is an IDispatch for the object.

I have the dll and its typelib as a resource.  What can i do?